# If a double-quoted string ends with an escaped backslash the lexer rule keeps matching characters as if they are part of the quoted string

Tags: c++, antlr, lexer

If a double-quoted string ends with an escaped backslash the lexer rule gets greedy and keeps matching characters as if they are part of the quoted string. Then the lexer thinks the double quote that actually starts the next quoted string is ending the first one and gives a syntax error on the following character. We’ll need to tweak the lexer rule to fix this.

The lexer rules are set in a .g4 file type.

Example: `string demo = "a\\b" + "c";` works fine but string demo1 = `"a\\" + "c"` gives out a syntax error saying that the expression is an invalid string.

Another example: `string demo = "a\\b" + "\\c";` gives out a syntax error too with the same error as above.

Can I know how to write lexer rules for this if someone has any experience in it.

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful, including sample input that's causing the issue and what you'd except.

Comment: I have updated the post with examples

Comment: my guess - you try to test with `char*str = "a\";`

Comment: please show complete, failing program

Comment: I have re stated the question after learning more about it

Answer (score 1):

The backslash is special, it acts as an escape character inside a string. If you want one in the string, you have to double it up `\\`.